# The error of a Taylor polynomial (relativistic kinetic energy)

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have been trying to utilize the formula:
[image]

I simply cannot figure out how to determine the error when using

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

I have made a Taylor polynomial around 0 of grade 4, and I cannot find the deviation when using the Taylor polynomial instead of the original function.

The Taylor polynomial is:
[image]

And it was made of the Lorentz factor:

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at Taylor-Lagrange formula ?

Comment: Yes I have, but I cannot figure out how to implement it. Every example of using it that I can find, uses the the natural exponential function or a trigonometric function, and their bound is easy to figure out.

Comment: You can get a bound on the error with Taylor-Lagrange as soon as you can calculate the Taylor series. What is blocking you ?

Comment: Well i have made the taylor series, but don't understand how i get the bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call $f(t)$ the function
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}} $$

The $k^{th}$ derivative function of $f()$ is equal to
$$f^{k}(t) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^k{(2i-1)}}{2^k} (1-t)^{-\frac{2k+1}{2}} $$
This last relation can for example be demonstrated by recurrence.

According to Taylor-Lagrange formula, there exists $\xi$ between $0$ and $t$ such that

$$f(t) = 1 + \frac{t}{2} + \frac{3}{8}t^2 + \frac{5}{16}(1-\xi)^{-7/2}\,t^3 = 1 + \frac{t}{2} + \frac{3}{8}t^2 + R(t)$$

It follows

$$0 < R(t) <  \frac{5}{16}(1-t)^{-7/2}\,t^3 $$

Now, one just have to replace $t$ :
$$t = x^2 = \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2$$